# Gulp is throwing an error. Did you forget to signal async compilation.?

Tags: javascript, drupal, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

gulp locale-sass :

```
return function(done) {
  ......
  if (fileSizeError) {
    console.log("Compiled CSS file size exceeds threshold value (MAX 1953 kb allowed)");
  } else {
    done();
  }
};
```

If fileSizeError block is triggered which is throwing

```
Did you forget to signal async compilation.?
```

If else block is executing the task is completed without any error. 
I have to hide error message some how. Beause am using pre-commit hooks due to some reason am using this condition. Just I need to hide an error message.

```
"scripts": {
  ........
  "deploy": "gulp deploy",
  "reset": "gulp reset",
  "locale-sass": "gulp locale-sass"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "gulp reset && gulp locale-sass"
    }
  },
```

Comment: I would put a `done()` call either at the end of the `if` clause too or at the end of the whole  function.

Comment: @Mark if I execute done() the gulp operation is success. My condition is gulp has to fail if fileSizeError is true. One option is using --silent at the end of gulp which will hide errors. For example gulp reset && gulp locale-sass --silent

Answer (score 0):

Add `done()` and pass the error to it as its only param:

```
return function(done) {
  ......
  if (fileSizeError) {
    console.log("Compiled CSS file size exceeds threshold value (MAX 1953 kb allowed)");
    done(fileSizeError);
  } else {
    done();
  }
};
```

See the [official documentation](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-an-error-first-callback).